# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'paperType'

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting this error when I try to hit the submit button on my form. I believe I'm getting this error because I haven't selected anything but I'm really not sure because I populate it when the user loads the form.

Here is my index method:

```
ViewBag.numOfPages = GetNumberOfPagesList();
        ViewBag.paperStyle = new SelectList(styleList, "Value", "Text");
        ViewBag.urgency = GetUrgencySelectList();
        ViewBag.subject = new SelectList(subjectList, "Value", "Text");
        ViewBag.paperType = GetPaperTypeSelectList();
        ViewBag.price = 0.00;
        ViewBag.spacing = "double";

        return View();
```

Here is the method that it calls to populate the list:

```
public SelectList GetPaperTypeSelectList()
    {
        var paperTypes = PaperType.GetPaperTypes();

        return new SelectList(paperTypes.ToArray(), "deadlineFormat", "typeName");
    }
```

Here is the view code for the select list in question:

```
<div class="row">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.paperType, (SelectList)ViewBag.paperType, new { id = "paperTypeJList" })
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.paperType, "Type of Paper:")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.paperType)
</div>
```

Here is my model code:

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Full Name is Required.")]
        public string fullName { get; set; }

```
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "A Valid Email Address is Required.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is Required.")]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber, ErrorMessage = "A Valid Email Address is Required.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone Number is Required.")]
    public string phone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Topic is Required.")]
    public string topic { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Subject is Required.")]
    public string subject { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Paper Type is Required.")]
    public string paperType { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Urgency is Required.")]
    public Int16 urgency { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Number of Pages is Required.")]
    public Int16 numOfPages { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requirements are Required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string requirements { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Writing Style is Required.")]
    public string style { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Spacing is Required.")]
    public string spacing { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")]
    [Range(0.01, 10000.00, ErrorMessage = "Your quote is not complete because you haven't completed all of the steps.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal price { get; set; }
```

Please let me know if you need anymore information. I read other questions about this error and I'm setting the information properly and the code to bind it looks correct as well. This code used to work but I don't remember changing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call this again in the post action as it will be lost after the form posted and view re-rendered ViewBag values are removed:

```
    ViewBag.numOfPages = GetNumberOfPagesList();
    ViewBag.paperStyle = new SelectList(styleList, "Value", "Text");
    ViewBag.urgency = GetUrgencySelectList();
    ViewBag.subject = new SelectList(subjectList, "Value", "Text");
    ViewBag.paperType = GetPaperTypeSelectList();
```

Comment: Won't that just overwrite my info in the model? How can I perform a check before to see if the value is valid or not? I want to make sure that they don't have the first item in the dropdownlist selected because that is just a placeholder

Comment: you have to take another parameter for selected and from post get that and set selected that one after form post, then your model will be retained in same position

Comment: your problem is after form post you get that error, ok? and that error is coming because after you action is called form View and View is returned back from action ViewBag values become null of Dropdowns so you need to repopulate them in the post action

Comment: yes I set the viewbag values in the post method but I'm still getting those errors. I'm checking the modelstate to see if it is valid and the price is coming back as null even though I'm setting it again in the post method. What is causing this?

Comment: check may be you put it in else condition put it outside if else so it is executed whether state valid or not